# Picking a certain part of a json response

Tags: javascript, json

After running a POST request to https://api.imgflip.com/caption_image - I get the response of something like:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "url": "http://i.imgflip.com/1nciey.jpg",
    "page_url": "https://imgflip.com/i/1nciey"
  }
}
```

How would I `console.log()` the string from the `url` part of the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response string is in [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format.

JavaScript can parse JSON strings by calling [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```
// str = the response string
var parsed_json = JSON.parse(str);
```

The variable `parsed_json` will now be a JavaScript object which you can use to reference desired properties, e.g. the url:

```
console.log('Response URL: ', parsed_json.data.url);
```